# Extract javascript gettext in Poedit?

Tags: javascript, html, gettext, php-gettext

I have used "GNU gettext" with PHP and it did a greate job by using poedit I was able to  extract the PO file format

but when I tried the same thing for my javascript inside my HTML "script" tag  I didn't work even more I can't see any javascript support.

poedit support almost all languages except javascript or I am doing it In a wrong way 
can anyone provide working example for javascript?!
i followed all example in almost 20 languages  using poedit and all worked except javascript

all working examples from GNU gettext found in

gettext-0.19.7.tar.gz

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gettext/

gettext-0.19.7\gettext-tools\examples

this is php examlpe which works i need to do the same for javascript

```
    #!@PHP@ -q
    <?
      // Example for use of GNU gettext.
      // This file is in the public domain.
      //
      // Source code of the PHP program.

      setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
      textdomain ("hello-php");
      bindtextdomain ("hello-php", "@localedir@");

      echo _("Hello, world!");
      echo "\n";
      echo printf (_("This program is running as process number %d."),posix_getpid());
      echo "\n";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Both Poedit and `xgettext` have support for JavaScript for some time now. Your problem is that you're embedding the code in HTML file, so it's not recognized as a JavaScript file (and `xgettext`, which Poedit uses, doesn't support embedded content in other languages).

Just put your JavaScript code in a separate `.js` file.

Notice that JavaScript code runs on the client side, so you need to load translations *in JavaScript* as well. A better solution for you, considering that you have just some (presumably small-ish) snippets of JS inside a PHP code, may be to generate that JS code with PHP — i.e. do the translation on PHP/server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gettext-parser) to work with those files, assuming you are working from a node environment. I do not think it is possible from the browser.

Comment: `gettext-parser` is gettext *runtime* that does only one thing: loads PO/MO files — it even says so in the first sentence on the linked page. It doesn't do *strings extractions*, which this question is about, at all.